# Apex callout to local web service or to web service in test environment?

Tags: web-services, proxy, salesforce, callouts

I'm pretty new to salesforce callout stuff and trying to make a simple GET request from my salesforce callout, but I kept getting this error:

```
System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

I'm pretty sure this is because I'm making request to the web service on my local machine, but since I'm only testing this out, I don't have a server that's available online.
I tried making a callout to just `http://www.google.com?q=blah` and it works just fine.

So I guess my question is that anyone has a way to make callout to a web service on their local machine?

Comment: What endpoint URL do you use to call your local ws?

Comment: It's to my local machine, so it's just localhost.blah./blah/blah
I can hit that URL via my browser but I can't from salesforce, which makes sense. So I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good way to test this thing

Comment: And how do you suppose Salesforce call your local ws? You are running your code on some Salesforce's server and calling local endpoint. Why it should call your ws?

Answer (score 1):

Just put your ip address instead of 'localhost' and that is it. If you have a router at work/home, you need setup it so it route internet calls to your PC.

That is how it works for me right now. I created a WS using Java. Started a server on 8080 port. From my SFDC application I call xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bla